# JNI class and interface naming

Tags: java-native-interface

inside my JNI test app, I use JNIViie as projet name. In this case I have

```
JNIViie.java
native lib: JNIViie.cpp / JNIViie.h finaly libJNIViie.so
```

Everything is woking fine.

```
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("JNIViie");
    }
```

and calling JNI function:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_JNIViie_getMediumInformation
  ( JNIEnv *env, jobject jobj );
```

is working fine. But now I want to use the `JNIViie` native lib inside an app calling `"MyApp"` but leave the native lib with the naming `JNIViie`. My question is now, is this possible or need the native lib the same naming as the app?

Comment: You could still have a `JNIViie` Java class in your other project.

Comment: Even more, you can have abstract methods with native and implement them slightly different way: http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-no-030/; note that naming convention has to mach only between the class that calls native library and native library itself. You can still call your code from another class.